# Not able to set run time permission in Android

Tags: android, permissions, runtime

I am trying to fetch permission to write in external storage on clicking the button. But when I am writing the following code but at   WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE it is showing red. How will I avoid It.

```
 scan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(BG1.this, new
                        String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_WRITE_PERMISSION);
            }
        });
```

Comment: where are u writing this code? post the full code

Comment: use android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Adding

```
android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

Let me know if its working perfectly and Accept the Answer!!

Answer (score 0):

As Manjunath Prabhakar said you need this line in your `Manifest` anyway if you still get this Exeption (And if not you maybe can in other devices), You will need 'Requesting Permissions at Run Time' [more information here](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)